# How to filter out rows based on information in other columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pricing policy table that determines the price a customer is given based on qty purchased as per below.

| debtor_code | stock_code | min_quantity | default_price | contract_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2393 | GRBAG100GTALL-50 | 0 | 295 | 236 |
| 2393 | GRBAG100GTALL-50 | 5 | 295 | 265.5 |
| 2393 | GRBAG100GTALL-50 | 10 | 295 | 221.25 |

The pricing offered is based on the cheapest `contract_price` available for the lowest qty, meaning that the second row is obsolete as the `min_quantity`, and the cheaper price from the first row overrides the second row.

How can I use a SQL Server query to filter out obsolete rows like this as the first row supersedes it by having a cheaper `contract_price` at a lower `min_quantity`.

The result should look like:

| debtor_code | stock_code | min_quantity | default_price | contract_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2393 | GRBAG100GTALL-50 | 0 | 295 | 236 |
| 2393 | GRBAG100GTALL-50 | 10 | 295 | 221.25 |

Comment: Which RBDMS are you using (Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, etc)? Please add its tag to your question.

Comment: What do you mean by `remove the obsolete row` ? You want to delete those rows from the table ? Please provide the expected query and your attempt query

Comment: @Squirrel I've edited the questions - I meant to filter the obsolete row out. As the first row supersedes it by having a cheaper `contract_price` at a lower `min_quantity`.

Comment: @Dale K I hadn't exactly tried anything as I had no idea how to accomplish this - it isn't exactly my job, but I incrementally learn Sql as needed to accomplish various things in my 'marketing' role. I did a lot of googling, but couldn't find anything that appeared to suit the situation - otherwise I wouldn't have asked! The query to arrive at the results (presented in my question as a table) is over 200 lines - running into this final problem seemed to be a problem that I couldn't get past without help.

Comment: No, because of how hard it is to describe an SQL problem its unlikely you'll find a matching solution. It sounds like you would benefit from taking a few tutorials to give yourself a better idea of the SQL options available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LEAD()` to find the next tier's `contract_price` and compare with current level. Set the flag and filter out accordingly in the final query.

Based on assumption that price at higher tier (higher min_quantity value) should be cheaper than current tier.

```
with cte as
(
    select *,
           case when lead(contract_price) over (partition by debtor_code 
                                                    order by min_quantity) < contract_price
                then 1
                else 0 
                end as flag
    from   pricing
 )
 select *
 from   cte
 where  flag = 0
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94aea6984af533bd4e0a02185fb8afde)

---

EDIT :

The following query uses recursive cte to compare current row with previous row to determine the validity of the price

```
with cte as
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by debtor_code, stock_code
                                          order by min_quantity)
    from   pricing
 ),
 rcte as
 (
     select debtor_code, stock_code, rn, min_quantity, default_price, 
            contract_price, 
            valid_price = contract_price, valid = 1
     from   cte
     where  rn = 1
     
     union all
     
     select c.debtor_code, c.stock_code, c.rn, c.min_quantity, c.default_price, 
            c.contract_price, 
            valid_price = case when c.contract_price < r.contract_price
                               then c.contract_price
                               else r.contract_price
                               end, 
            valid       = case when c.contract_price < r.contract_price
                               then 1
                               else 0
                               end
     from   rcte r
            inner join cte c on r.rn = c.rn - 1
)          
select  *
from   rcte
where  valid = 1
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b26a5a0001a35c053a6974e3346fdf3f)

---

Edit 2

A much simplified solution. First is to find the `min(contract_price)` in the sequence of `min_quantity`. Then simply compare the current `contract_price` with that. It is same or equal, it is valid

```
select * 
from
(
    select *, valid_price = min(contract_price) 
                            over (partition by debtor_code, stock_code
                                      order by min_quantity)
    from   pricing
) p
where contract_price <= valid_price
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dac5631b1b31177c0bb019dc525fc1f9)

Comment: Thanks @squirrel, that works well for the provided example, however doesn't if more obsolete rows are added as per https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5e4cecad6913dba5334e7d7276b2804

Comment: updated the answer with recursive version

Comment: Awesome thank you! This works providing the initial data is sorted by `min_quantity` then `contract_price`

Comment: Note : data is not sorted in table. The sequence or ordering of rows is determine by `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: You've made my day! My actual query to arrive at the pricing data is a lot more complicated, but I've been able to adapt your Edit 2 solution to work with my query.